# SCOM integration with webservices

Tags: powershell, system-center, scom

How to create a SCOM connector to send the alerts to Rest API??
I have identified one of the possible solution.

1. Make the SCOM notification services catch your alerts (or all 
   alerts)
2. Create the PS script where you can implement additional filtering and running the external API call

So now I wanted get the PS script which can send specific resolution state alerts to webservices. 
Can you please help me to get the PS script??

Thanks in Advance 
Mano